# How can I access a JS object I have defined?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following object:

```
var IOBreadcrumb = {
    breadcrumbs: [],

    add: function(title, url){
      var crumb = {
        title: title, 
        url:url
      };
      this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    }
  };
```

How can I access the object?

```
var breadcrumb = new IOBreadcrumb();
breadcrumb.add('some title','some url');
console.log(breadcrumb.breadcrumbs);
```

Gives me an `Uncaught Type Error: object is not a function` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use `new` on an object but it can only actually target functions.  Try the following instead

```
var IOBreadcrumb = function IOBreadcrumb() {
  this.breadcrumbs = [];
  this.add = function(title, url) {
    var crumb = {
      title: title, 
      url:url
    };
    this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
  };
};
```

Alternatively you could also take advantage of the prototype here and share the definition of `add` amongst several instancces

```
var IOBreadcrumb = function IOBreadcrumb() {
  this.breadcrumbs = [];
};

IOBreadcrumb.prototype.add = function (title, url) {
  var crumb = {
    title: title, 
    url:url
  };
  this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
};
```

Comment: It's also nice to give your function a name, ie. `var IOBreadcrumb = function IOBreadcrub() { ... };`. This way you can call `instance.constructor.name` and get back the type `IOBreadcrumb`.

Comment: @Peter wasn't aware of that.  Is that standard behavior?

Comment: @Peter: [JScriptbugs](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs). At least older IEs (7) and Operas (9.64) don't support `instance.constructor.name`.

Comment: No, I just checked, the `name` property isn't standard :( ... yet.

Comment: @Peter even if it's not standard it doesn't appear to have a negative effect here if the only purpose is for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
function IOBreadcrumb() {
    var breadcrumbs = [];

    this.add = function(title, url){
      var crumb = {
        title: title, 
        url:url
      };
      breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    }
  };
```

Should do it, quite literally, its not a function ;)

Comment: If you'd accepted my edit, it wouldn't have been down-voted :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `IOBreadcrumb.add('some title','some url');`

Currently `IOBreadcrumb` is an object with the static function `add`. If you want to make an instance of `IOBreadcrumb`, you would make it a function.

```
var IOBreadcrumb = function() {
  this.breadcrumbs = [];
  this.add = function(title, url) {
    this.breadcrumbs.push({
      title: title,
      url: url
    });
  };
};

var breadcrumb = new IOBreadcrumb();
breadcrumb.add('some title','some url');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createIOBreadcrumb() {
    return {
        breadcrumbs: [],

        add: function(title, url) {
            var crumb = {
                title: title, 
                url:url
            };
            this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
        };
    };
}


var breadcrumb = createIOBreadcrumb();
```